# Error: No response has been set. Cloud Functions for Actions on Google Assistant

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

I am building an **Assistant** app for Google Home, using **Dialogflow**, **Cloud Functions** and the new **NodeJS Client** Library V2 for **Actions on Google**. In fact I am in the process of migrating my old code built with V1 to V2.

**The Context**

I am trying to get the user's location using two seperate intents: `Request Permission` (Intent that triggers/send permission request to the user) and `User Info` (Intent that checks if the user granted permission and then returns the data requested by the assistant to continue.

**The Issue**

The problem is that the same code that was working just fine on V1 isn't working on V2. So I had to do some refactoring. And when I deploy my cloud function I am able to successfully request the user's permission, get his location and then using an external library (`geocode`), I can convert the latlong to a human readable form. but for some reasons (I think its promises) I can't resolve the promise object and show it to the user

**The Error**

I get the error below:

[image]

**The Code**

Below is my Cloud function code. I have tried multiple versions of this code, using the `request` library, `https` library, etc. No luck...No luck

```
    const {dialogflow, Suggestions,SimpleResponse,Permission} = require('actions-on-google')  
    const functions = require('firebase-functions'); 
    const geocoder = require('geocoder');

    const app = dialogflow({ debug: true });

    app.middleware((conv) => {
        conv.hasScreen =
            conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT');
        conv.hasAudioPlayback =
            conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT');
    });

    function requestPermission(conv) {
        conv.ask(new Permission({
            context: 'To know who and where you are',
            permissions: ['NAME','DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION']
        }));
    }

    function userInfo ( conv, params, granted) {

        if (!conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION')) {

            // Note: Currently, precise locaton only returns lat/lng coordinates on phones and lat/lng coordinates 
            // and a geocoded address on voice-activated speakers. 
            // Coarse location only works on voice-activated speakers.
            conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
                speech:'Sorry, I could not find you',
                text: 'Sorry, I could not find you'
            }))
            conv.ask(new Suggestions(['Locate Me', 'Back to Menu',' Quit']))
        }

        if (conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION')) {

            const permission = conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION'); // also retrievable with explicit arguments.get
            console.log('User: ' + conv.user)
            console.log('PERMISSION: ' + permission)
            const location = conv.device.location.coordinates
            console.log('Location ' + JSON.stringify(location))

            // Reverse Geocoding
            geocoder.reverseGeocode(location.latitude,location.longitude,(err,data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }


                // console.log('geocoded: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
                console.log('geocoded: ' + JSON.stringify(data.results[0].formatted_address))
                conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
                    speech:'You currently at ' + data.results[0].formatted_address + '. What would you like to do now?',
                    text: 'You currently at ' + data.results[0].formatted_address + '.'
                }))
                conv.ask(new Suggestions(['Back to Menu', 'Learn More', 'Quit']))

            })

        }

    }


    app.intent('Request Permission', requestPermission);
    app.intent('User Info', userInfo);

    exports.myCloudFunction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right on your last guess - your problem is that you're not using Promises.

`app.intent()` expects the handler function (`userInfo` in your case) to return a Promise if it is using async calls. (If you're not, you can get away with returning nothing.)

The normal course of action is to use something that returns a Promise. However, this is tricky in your case since the geocode library hasn't been updated to use Promises, and you have other code that in the `userInfo` function that doesn't return anything.

A rewrite in this case might look something like this (I haven't tested the code, however). In it, I break up the two conditions in `userInfo` into two other functions so one can return a Promise.

```
function userInfoNotFound( conv, params, granted ){
  // Note: Currently, precise locaton only returns lat/lng coordinates on phones and lat/lng coordinates 
  // and a geocoded address on voice-activated speakers. 
  // Coarse location only works on voice-activated speakers.
  conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
    speech:'Sorry, I could not find you',
    text: 'Sorry, I could not find you'
  }))
  conv.ask(new Suggestions(['Locate Me', 'Back to Menu',' Quit']))
}

function userInfoFound( conv, params, granted ){
  const permission = conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION'); // also retrievable with explicit arguments.get
  console.log('User: ' + conv.user)
  console.log('PERMISSION: ' + permission)
  const location = conv.device.location.coordinates
  console.log('Location ' + JSON.stringify(location))

  return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ){
    // Reverse Geocoding
    geocoder.reverseGeocode(location.latitude,location.longitude,(err,data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        reject( err );
      } else {
        // console.log('geocoded: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
        console.log('geocoded: ' + JSON.stringify(data.results[0].formatted_address))
        conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
          speech:'You currently at ' + data.results[0].formatted_address + '. What would you like to do now?',
          text: 'You currently at ' + data.results[0].formatted_address + '.'
        }))
        conv.ask(new Suggestions(['Back to Menu', 'Learn More', 'Quit']))
        resolve()
      }
    })
  });

}

function userInfo ( conv, params, granted) {
  if (conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION')) {
    return userInfoFound( conv, params, granted );
  } else {
    return userInfoNotFound( conv, params, granted );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @prisoner. Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I have few questions;  
  
Given your solution, How would you go about configuring the Dialogflow part of this? Looking at your code, it seems to me that I will have to drop the `RequestPermission` Intent and only use the `UserInfo` intent to request the permission & display location.  

My original intention was to have 2 Intents: One that sole purpose is to trigger a permission request & from there any other intent will use it to get user data.

I hope you can clarify that for me. But I will try your code and see what happens

Comment: I maintained using the UserInfo intent to do this - I just split the two parts that were in "if" statements into separate functions to make it clearer which one needed to return a Promise and how it did so.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me alot, and saved my a nights efforts.

Comment: @Prisoner, If I was calling a second method after the first, would a '.then()…', after resolving the first work please?

Comment: Yes, that is the normal way to use Promises with `.then()` chains (or using the `await` syntax in Node8+). If you have further questions - opening a new StackOverflow question with as many details and example code about where you're having problems is the best approach to getting it answered.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Prisoner, I was able to make it work. i didn't have to modify my Dialogflow structure or anything. All I had to do was change the Reverse Geocoding section to what @Prisoner suggested. And it worked for me.

```
//Reverse Geocoding

return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ){
    // Reverse Geocoding
    geocoder.reverseGeocode(location.latitude,location.longitude,(err,data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        reject( err );
      } else {
        // console.log('geocoded: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
        console.log('geocoded: ' + JSON.stringify(data.results[0].formatted_address))
        conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
          speech:'You currently at ' + data.results[0].formatted_address + '. What would you like to do now?',
          text: 'You currently at ' + data.results[0].formatted_address + '.'
        }))
        conv.ask(new Suggestions(['Back to Menu', 'Learn More', 'Quit']))
        resolve()
      }
   })
});
```

I can now move on to other things!