# Is it possible to access the argument of an arrow function from another nested arrow function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, actions-on-google, arrow-functions

I'm trying to build a backend webhook for the Google Assistant that reads records from DynamoDB.

This is my code:

```
// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'trip name'.
// The intent collects a parameter named 'tripName'.
app.intent('trip name', (conv, {tripName}) => {

    const dynamoDb = IS_OFFLINE === true ?
        new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
            region: 'ap-south-1',
            // endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
        }) :
        new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
            region: 'ap-south-1',
            // endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
        });


        const params = {
            TableName: ACTIVITIES_TABLE
            Key: {
                'name':tripName
            }
        };

        // conv.close('error retrieving!'); THIS WORKS
        dynamoDb.get(params, (error, result) => {
            // conv.close('error retrieving!'); THIS DOES NOT

            if (error) {
                conv.close('error retrieving!');
            }
            else {
                conv.close(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
            }
        });
});
```

If I were to use `conv` from outside the DynamoDB function it works, but from inside it does not and return this error:

> 2019-08-03T03:56:22.521Z  **  ERROR   Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was
>   not returned as a promise to the intent handler?

It made me conclude that maybe I'm not allowed to access an arrow function argument from another nested arrow function?

I'm using [Actions on Google Client Library](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs).

Comment: You're allowed to do that, but not with the framework you're using.

Comment: I updated the question about what library I'm using. @JackBashford

Comment: Can you add `conv` as an argument to the nested function? `dynamoDb.get(params, (error, result, conv) => {...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: No response has been set. Cloud Functions for Actions on Google Assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909455/error-no-response-has-been-set-cloud-functions-for-actions-on-google-assistant)

Comment: If you do some **async calls** like quering DB you need to **return a promise**.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with accessing parameters from one arrow function in another - that is perfectly allowed.

The issue is, as the error message suggests, that you are using an asynchronous function (a function that requires a callback0, but not returning a `Promise` object. The actions-on-google library requires you to return a `Promise` from your Intent Handler if you're doing any asynchronous operations so it knows to wait for those operations to complete.

You'll need to switch from using a callback in your call to `dynamoDb.get()` to using a `Promise` instead. To do this, you need to not include the callback function, so `get()` returns an [`AWS.Request`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html) object. This object has a `promise()` method, so you would use this to return the results from the [Promise and then() chain](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/). (And you must return this `Promise`.)

In your case, it might look something like this

```
    return dynamoDb.get(params).promise()
      .then( result => {
        conv.close(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
      })
      .catch( error => {
        conv.close('error retrieving!');
      });
```